# Android basic question

Tags: android

I am new to Android.
can anyone tell me about Android that how can we run sample application on eclipse in android.while i run emulator opens but nothing is displayed on the screen.
Even HelloWorld Application is also not runnning.

My setup appears to be correct, I verified again.

Comment: The emulator sometimes starts extremely slowly. On one of my computers, it took about 15 minutes to load it (on linux. On a windows computer with the same parameters it takes only one or two minutes), and until that i only saw an "android" text in the center. Try to start the emulator from the android sdk manager instead of eclipse, and check the cpu usage of the emulator. It's so high while loading, so you can see if it's the only problem. It's just a hint. Maybe you have some totally different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Eclipse, read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

You can refer toturials point site as it cover all the basics of android in general which i feel is good for beginners, here is the link. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_tutorial.pdf